# Как получить сообщение на которое ответили? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Как получить сообщение, в ответ на которое была отправлена команда, и ответить на него же.

То-есть например:

```
User1 - text
User2 - reply user1: !command
Bot - reply user1: text2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого создайте команду. Пусть будет .say

```
@client.command()
async def say(ctx, text):
```

Добавляем проверку для сообщения. То есть если пользователь ответил на сообщение командой .say {text}

```
    if ctx.message.reference:
        original = await ctx.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id)
        await original.reply(f'Вам сообщение: {text}')
```

Таким образом бот ответит на сообщение на которое ответили Вы.